How can i visualise node-cache data, similar to redis-commander for redis
Is there a way I can visualise my node-cache data similar to redis-commander for redis?
Actually I m using node-cache for api data caching, some times I faces issue on production environment, which i can only trouble shoot via console logs, and if I add console log for node-cache on each line, that will be a mess to code as well for console. I was looking towards to see some web based solution to monitor the values.
I tried to separate out logs in a text file for latest values but it reduces the performance for API, so I m looking towards some web based solution.

You can try building your own express server and request node-cache data via api but there is already ui built for the purpose.
You can try npm package node-cache-commander,
Code snippet:
const {
  initializeNodeCacheCommander,
  addNodeCacheInstance,
} = require("node-cache-commander"); //Import
const NodeCache = require("node-cache"); //Import Node-cache
initializeNodeCacheCommander(3000, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"); //
const myCache = new NodeCache(); //Initialize node-cache instance
const myCache2 = new NodeCache(); //Initialize node-cache instance if needed (just for example here)
let obj = { my: "Special", variable: 42 }; //
myCache.set("myKey", obj, 10000); // Set values
let obj2 = { my: "Special2", variable: 42 }; //
myCache2.set("myKey1", obj, 10000); // Set Values

addNodeCacheInstance({ name: "Node-instance-1", v: myCache }); //Add instance to node-cache-commander to monitor
addNodeCacheInstance({ name: "Node-instance-2", v: myCache2 }); //Add instance to node-cache-commander to monitor

You can jump to web browser using ip/localhost:3000, to visualise data. Make sure to put proper credentials during initialisation.

After testing it, I think this works well.

For node-cache, there isn't a direct tool like redis-commander that provides a web-based interface for visualizing the cache data. However, you can create a simple solution using Express.js to build a custom dashboard.
